# Docusign Connect Audit Events

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, digital-signature

DocuSign webhooks sends 1 envelope per message. It can also return the respective child entities if they have been configured so (e.g. documents, recipients).

I wanted to receive audit events of the envelope (when someone opened or viewed) in the message as well.

Is it possible? Or is it only possible through polling? What is the recommended strategy?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Please **accept** (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The DocuSign webhook notification messages are sent per `webhook event`. There are events at the envelope level (Draft, Sent, Delivered, Completed, Declined, or Voided) and for each recipient (Sent, Delivered, Completed, Declined, AuthenticationFailed, and AutoResponded).

The audit event of a `recipient viewing` an envelope is available as the `Delivered` **recipient** event.

There are other audit events which are not available as webhook events. To track those you'd need to poll. Remember the DocuSign limit of polling no more often than once per 15 minutes per envelope. (And the overall API limit of 1,000 calls per hour.)

If you subscribe to the recipient.Delivered event then you'll receive a webhook message when a recipient views the envelope. See the `Delivered` date stamp for the recipient and the `Delivered` status.

**BUT** if you have the webhook system set to aggregate notification messages (the default) then individual notifications may be aggregated together. For example, if you're subscribing to both the recipient delivered and completed events, and a recipient opens (delivered) and then immediately signs (completed) the envelope, you may only get one notification, for the later (completed) event.

But your code can look for the delivered date stamp to see if the envelope was delivered.

Comment: Very insightful. So, even if someone views multiple times, only 1 event will be sent (delivered status) which corresponds to the time point the recipient opened it for the first time. To track how many times a person opened the envelope, the only way is to poll listAuditEvents() 15 in 15 minutes. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know if the `Delivered` date stamp is updated for subsequent views. Please test it out and let us know!

Comment: Gonna try it out!